# ffmpeg aliased jpeg input in overlay

Tags: video, ffmpeg, jpeg, overlay, antialiasing

I have to overlay a video with 1 jpeg image (various sizes) during x seconds and in the result the image appears aliased. I searched a lot but i didn't found which parameters to tune to have a render without aliasing. Can you help me?

Thanks in advance,

This is my command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i videosource.mp4 -loop 1 -i 640x480.jpg \
    -filter_complex "[1:v] pad=1280:720:(1280- iw)/2:(720- ih)/2 [o1v]; [0:v][o1v] overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2:enable='between(t,0,10)':format=yuv420 [V]" \
    -map "[V]" -q:v 2 -map 0:a  -c:a copy -crf 1 -shortest output.mp4
```

**Input image:**

[image: input image]

**The pixelated result (open the second file to see it pixelated):**

[image: the pixelated result (open the second file to see it aliased)]